# In Xcode 4, how do I build the "Debug", "Ad hoc" and "Store" settings?

Tags: xcode4

With the new Xcode 4, I imported a Xcode 3 project. I used to have three different sets of build settings, for "Debug", "Ad hoc" and "Store". Now, I don't find them anywhere in the new interface. The settings (like code signing options) are still there in the build settings, but how do I select one or the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can edit scheme and assign different configuration for different actions. Adhoc configuration for archiving for example.

Click 'Scheme' button and select 'Edit scheme'. You'll see 'Archive' item which allow you to change configuration for archiving application.

Comment: Any idea how to edit those different build configurations in xcode 4?

Comment: Select your project in Xcode. You'll see two tabs 'Info' and 'Build Settings'. Open 'Info' tab and edit/add configurations.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode4 you basically create a build and sign it afterwards, while in Xcode3 you had to select this upfront.

Archive your app (Product > Archive) and in the Organizer select the Archives tab. Here you can select an archived app and when you share it, you can select a provisioning profile (for instance your ad hoc provisioning profile) to sign it with.

Comment: But my Ad hoc and Store versions have also different build settings (macros), not only signing. How to I select one set of build parameters or another?

Comment: This was a very helpful answer for me.  It's confusing that Build Configurations are used differently now, but now I see that archives are signed later it makes a lot more sense.  Thanks Yannick.